# Делегирование в JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть такая разметка:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="main-slide">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/650x400/8a8a8a/fff" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="slide-bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/858111/fff" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/858222/fff" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/858333/fff" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/858444/fff" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/858555/fff" alt=""></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как с помощью JavaScript я могу подцепить клик по элементам li?

Такой код не работает:

```
var some = document.getElementById('slide-bar').getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].getElementsByTagName('li');
some.onclick = function(){};
```

Comment: Вы не сделали 1) цикл, 2) не вошли в "подкаталог" ul (firstChild).

Comment: Что значит подцепить? Подписаться на событие? Выбрать все элементы. Пройтись по всем элементам и добавить событие `addEventListener('click', function (){/*чтохотитеделатьприклике*/})`

Comment: Нужно сделать так что-бы при клике на любой из "li" происходило одинаковое действие.

Answer (score 1):

https://plnkr.co/edit/YDViqpOH2Zm0MRouUvPZ?p=preview

```
document.addEventListener("click", // здесь повесили обработчик на весь документ и на все клики
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.hasAttribute("data-slider")) { // здесь непосредственно ловим клик по нужному элементу
      alert('Спасибо!')
    }
  });
```

Только чтобы клик отработал поправь немного css стили и назначь элементу **li** {display: block} 
или лови клик на самой ссылке(тэг a). 
Ну и чем удобен этот подход, так это тем, что остальные события можно тут же и фильтовать.